# What really is the real impact?

Tags: support, profile-page

On my profile page, there is an IMPACT block. It says "X number of people reached". But when you hover over it, the tooltip says "estimated number of times people viewed ..." Soooo, that is weird. A single person can view my content 10 different times, resulting in 10 views. But that is till — one person. Right? What am missing here?

"The number of people who viewed the page" is not the same as "the number of times the page was viewed", or is it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the tooltip ("Estimated number of times people viewed your helpful posts") is actually a pretty good explanation of what the metric is. A lot better than just 'people reached'. It is a [rather inaccurate number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/295232) but an interesting metric nonetheless, looking at your contributions in another way than the well-known reputation and badges.

> A single person can view my content 10 different times, resulting in 10 views. But that is till — one person. Right?

Yes, that's correct. Every new visit, even by the same person, is counted again, unless it happens within 15 minutes of the previous visit.

Comment: Is there a way of knowing which of my posts is getting views? Like from which post am I getting "estimated number of times people viewed..."?

Comment: rene wrote a SEDE query for that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264626/295232)